# Not all nodes used in Spark Standalone cluster

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-standalone

I have made a Spark Standalone Cluster with two virtual machines.
In the 1st VM (8 cores, 64 GB Memory), I started the master manually using the command
`bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master`.
In the 2nd VM (8 cores, 64 GB Memory), I started the slave manually using
`bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://<hostname of master>:7077`.
Then in the 1st VM, I also started the slave using the above slave command. It can be seen in the below pic that both the workers & master are started & ALIVE.

But when I run my Spark applications only the worker in 2nd VM is run ( `worker-20160613102937-10.0.37.150-47668` ). The worker of 1st VM ( `worker-20160613103042-10.0.37.142-52601` ) doesn't run. See the below pic

[image: Spark Standalone Cluster UI]

I want both the workers should be used in my Spark applications. How can this be done?

**EDIT** : See this pic of Executor summary where the Executors corresponding to worker in VM 1st are failed.

[image: Executor Summary]

When I click on any `stdout` or `stderr`, it shows the error of `invalid log directory`. See the below pic

[image: error]

Comment: Are you certain that the input data you are processing is big enough to be splitted across 2 executor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is resolved. Spark was not able to create the log directory on the 1st VM. The user from which I was submitting the Spark job didn't have the permission to create a file on the path `/usr/local/spark`. Just changing the read/write permissions of the directory (`chmod -R 777 /usr/local/spark`) did the trick.